# Python's strftime doesn't follow ISO standard

Tags: python, datetime, iso, weekday

Can someone explain why the weekday start is different between `datetime.weekday()` and `strftime`,
where in `weekdays()` they start from Monday and in `strftime` they start from Sunday?

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday):

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. The same as `self.date().weekday()`. See also [`isoweekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoweekday).

[strftime.org](https://strftime.org/)

> `%w`   Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday.

Comment: Probably because `strftime` is based on the C standard.

Comment: You don't need to reference a third-party site; the codes are documented here: [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: @MrFuppes "%W Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0", i need the day number